# Objective-C: Get an objects class and cast the object to it dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, casting

Let's say I have a collection of objects of different types/classes, i.e. an NSArray.

I know that all of this objects inherit from NSManagedObject and all of them have a property named "uuid".

Now, I want to loop over this array, retrieve each objects uuid and add it to another array, like this:

```
NSMutableArray *objectUUIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (NSObject *object in objects) {
    // somehow cast the object to its class, so that I can send get its uuid
}
```

Actually, I could check for the class by `[object class]` in an if-else-clause, and cast it respectively, but as I have 30 something classes, I would like to do something more generic, like (in pseudo code):

```
// give me the object's true class instead of NSManagedObject
// add the object uuid to my objectUUIDs array
```

Comment: I don't get it...whats the goal of this? why not just treat them all as NSManagedObjects?

Comment: Type casting is an inherently static (non-dynamic) operation. It happens at compile time. There are no actual objects in any actual array at compile time.

Comment: I'd avise you to take a look at some OOP basics again

Comment: @Daij-Djan because if I treat them as NSManagedObjects, ´object.uuid` does not compile. OOP basics: Maybe you can give a search keyword, so I know for what I need to google?

Comment: viking's answer will do... you don't even need the cast to NSManagedObject and ngriff shows the classic text book solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say all objects are NSManagedObjects and all have a property uuid, you can use [Key-Value-Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1)

```
NSMutableArray *objectUUIDs = [@[] mutableCopy];
for (NSManagedObject *object in objects) {
    [objectUUIDs addObject: [object valueForKey:@"uuid"]];
}
```

---

or

```
NSArray *objectUUIDs = [objects valueForKey:@"uuid"];
```

[`NSArray's -valueForKey` doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCIBCDJ)

---

if you enumerate over an collection of objects of different classes you shouldn't type the enumerated object NSObject, but use either the closest common super class, or `id` — the generic objective-C object type. The reason is that you can send any message to an object typed with `id`, and you can do further testing. With other more concrete classes you must ensure a message is under stud by an given method.

---

You state

> ```
> // give me the object's true class instead of NSManagedObject
> ```

The object doesn't change during casting. if you put a instance of `MyFabulousManagedObject` (subclass of NSManagedObject) in an array, and later you cast it to `NSManagedObject`, it is actually still an instance of `MyFabulousManagedObject`

Comment: Yes, I understand your this. My problem was that, although I know that all my subclasses of NSManagedObject have a property of uuid, I did not know how to access it without casting. But thanks, now I learned for what KVO is good for. Thanks viking + nhgrif

Answer (score 3):

While *vikingosegundo*'s solution is probably best, there's also this possibility:

Define a protocol which has this property (or anything you know for sure is shared among all the objects):

```
@protocol FooBarProtocol
@property NSUUID *uuid;
@end
```

Now iterate over the original array as such:

```
NSMutableArray *objectUUIDs = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id<FooBarProtocol> object in objects) {
    [objectUUIDs addObject:object.uuid];   
}
```

Here, we're simply casting the objects all to objects that conform to `FooBarProtocol`, although it may be true that all of your objects already conform to a protocol that defines this property, or perhaps all have a common superclass with this property defined.

The main point here is that you just need to cast them to anything that defines the property.

---

Note that as written, this will crash if the object actually doesn't have a `uuid` property.  Might be a good idea to add:

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(uuid)]) {
    [objectUUIDs addObject:object.uuid];
}
```

And this also avoids having a massive chain of `if` statements to check all the different classes.  We don't care what sort of class it is.  We only care that it can give us a `UUID`.

Comment: :) I was wandering if I should also add that.

Comment: Yeah.  I mainly point this out because ideally all of the objects already have a common superclass with this property defined or conform to a protocol with this property defined already.  And this is the one thing your answer didn't cover.

Comment: @nhgrif instead of respondsToSelector i'd now use conformsToProtocol:fooBarProtocol -- it is more text book like

Comment: NOTE: id use KVC like viking did and use respondsToSelector ;)

Comment: @Daij-Djan I almost did `conformsToProtocol:`, however objects will only answer `YES` to this if they're explicitly defined as conforming to the protocol in their header file, right?  In this case, as we're casting them to this protocol we've defined only for the sake of this loop, they'd all answer `NO` to that call.

Comment: If I knew beforehand, it would prefer the 'protocol' approach, because it seems to me more safe (better dealing with design-time errors than run-time errors). But KVO enables me in this case not to modify existing code AND I KNOW, that all my objects have a property of uuid. nhgrif's code ensures, that there will be no crash, which is great too. Thanks all for the enlightened discussions. I am coming from Java , which is statically typed, and now I got a grasp why dynamical typed languages are sometimes better.

Comment: @mradlmaier With my code you don't have to do any modification more than what you have to do with *viking*'s code.  The protocol definition can go in the file you have the `forin` loop.  You don't have to change every class as conforming to the protocol.  You can simply cast them to an object conforming to the protocol within the loop.

Comment: @nhgrif OK, I see, so protocols are indeed a bit different from interfaces in Java...